# Is there a way to create a dict object from user input() in python 3.7.1?

Tags: python-3.x, user-input

The purpose of this question is I want to write some request through `pymongo`.
For one criterion per field, this is not a difficulty to use input.

```
find_mongo = {}
key = input("enter a field :")
value = input("enter a criterion :")
find_mongo[key] = value

db.collection.find(find_mongo)#it works without problem.
```

That's more problematic when I want more complicated criteria.
For instance if I want the value to be in a range:

`{"field":{"$lte":1,"$gte":0.5,"$exists:true"}}`

Because for the user, who's my own-self, it would be very easier to write this in the shell:

```
enter a field : size
enter a criterion or criteria : {"$lte":1,"$gte":0.5,"$exists":true"}
```

the current issue is `value` returns a string object : `'{"$lte":1,"$gte":0.5,"$exists":true"}'`
and as far as I know, mongo is not able to find with a `str` expression but with a `dict`.

I want this too if I need to write even more complicated requests with "$or" nested in a "$and" expression:

```
{"$and":[
         {"size":{"$lte":100}},
         { $or: [ { quantity: { $lt: 20 } }, { price: 10 } ] }
         ]
}
```

and just have to write in an input the following example:

```
enter your request: {"$and":[
             {"size":{"$lte":100}},
             { $or: [ { quantity: { $lt: 20 } }, { price: 10 } ] }
             ]}
```

in order to be able to execute:

```
find_mongo = input("enter your request: ")
db.collection.find(find_mongo)
```

Sure it's easier from the mongoshell, but if I don't request from mongoshell is because I want to make transformation of the files of the request in python.
Besides I am not searching for a solution to obtain `{"$lte":1,"$gte":0.5,"$exists":true"}`. Honestly with some reflections, conditions and iterations, I think I am able to find a way. I am really searching if it is possible to enter and return an object, here a `dict` and not an `str` one, through the `input()` user. Just because it's easier for me if such a solution does exist.

Notes: Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.7.1

Comment: Why not read in a .json file?  `{ $or: [ { quantity: { $lt: 20 } }, { price: 10 } ] }` is invalid Python/JSON BTW.

Comment: @ggorlen (here the doc)[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/], sorry if this is not something that works in pymongo, it was really to show a purpose above all. What you mean by "read in a .json file"? I want to do request.

Comment: Thanks--I'm not too familiar with Mongo, but I see that you're typing this in, so maybe omitting the quotes is OK since Python gets a string. My mistake. In any case, I'd just write your request as a .json file, then tell your script to read the file and send the request. Using `input()` and typing in queries by hand seems very onerous.

Comment: @ggorlen in order to use `json.loads()` on it? it seems to be a great idea. I will try it.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly right. If you *really* want to use `input()` at that point, you can type in the path to the json file, but even here I would look into `sys.argv`, so you can just do `python mymongoqueryapp ./myquery.json` or something.

Comment: @ggorlen I didn't need to write a json file. `str` object from the `input()` where I apply `json.loads()` works very well for me. Thanks.